# How to overlay divs that are being displayed inline?

Tags: html, css

I have a few div containers and I want to overlay a div container on all of them. I am displaying the bottom div container inline. How can I get the top div to show ontop of the bottom div with pure html and css. Here is my code:

html:

```
    <div class="single-resume">
        <img src="{% static 'resumes/images/jakarta-resume.jpg' %}">
        <div class="resume-info">This is some content</div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.single-resume {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

.resume-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

As you can see, I want the resume-div to overlay the .single-resume div. How can I get this to happen while still preserving .single-resume's display: inline? There will be many divs being overlayed. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as it stands as `inline` elements will not "take" a height or width value and so your `absolute`element cannot "inherit" those values.

I would recommend using `inline-block` rather than `inline`.

```css
.single-resume {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.resume-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="single-resume">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200">
  <div class="resume-info">This is some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked but unfortunately I won't be able to display my images inline.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you will achieve by continuing to use `display:inline` that cannot also be achieved with `inline-block`.